# Do I need to alter PYTHONPATH when I'm using venv?

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm creating a Django project inside a folder ("") protected by a virtual environment with venv (I ran "path/to/python -m venv " and "source bin/activate". I then ran "pip install django" with success. But when I tried to use django-admin I got

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'...
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

I checked site-modules inside TOPDIR, and found the django packages as expected. I then added the local site-modules folder to $PYTHONPATH in my $HOME/.profile. After I ran "source $HOME/.profile" I was able to make my django commands work.

My question is: Is this the preferred way to make a virtual environment's site-modules folder available? If so, will I have to edit $HOME/.profile this way every time I create a new virtual environment?

Comment: Are you using any text editor?

Comment: no, you definitely should not have to mess with PYTHONPATH ever just to use a module you pip-installed inside an environment

Comment: but figuring out whats going wrong is going to require you to give a lot of details, and showing the result of running these commands in your terminal would be the first place to start.

Comment: SOLVED, although I still don't know what went wrong in the first place. I removed the new line from PYTHONPATH, deleted the entire contents of my top folder and started over. This time, pip didn't install django, but referred to an already-installed package:
`jonathan$ python -m pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.1.7)`
With that, I was able to create and run my Django project. Thank you all!